# Devise Admin User for Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, devise, routes, activeadmin

ive set up active admin on rails 3.2.1 and its working great

i want to setup the AdminUser as a resource of ActiveAdmin but with the full devise routes, actions, methods, and redirects.

currently i have

**app/admin/admin_users.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser do

  menu :priority => 1, :label => "Admin Users"

  form do |f|
    f.inputs :email, :password, :password_confirmation
    f.buttons
  end

end
```

does anyone know of a good resource for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you explain what you're after in a bit more detail? ActiveAdmin automatically sets up your devise routes and actions for authentication and password recovery. If you're looking to create the CRUD interface, your AdminUser is just like any other resource in ActiveAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't seen this tutorial on ActiveAdmin, I'd highly recommend it: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/create-beautiful-administration-interfaces-with-active-admin/

I think it'll have some of the answers you're looking for. Especially passing blocks to column items to customize the links and routes. Checkout steps 2 and 5 and I think that should help solve your problem.